# Enable press and hold for right-clicking with

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working with a WPF application.This application runs on a pc with a touch screen and when I push one button for more than 3 seconds `MyButton_PreviewMouseUp` event occurs and after that occurs a `MyButtonSimple_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` event. I need to disable something for disabling the function of windows that do this.

Comment: Your title says you want to enable, your question needs to disable. What exactly is the problem and what exactly do are you trying to do?

Comment: What behaviour would you expect instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are not describing the default behaviour of a `Button`. In a normal WPF application, the `PreviewMouseUp` event occurs only when a pressed mouse button is let go. You can easily prove this yourself by adding a `Button` to a new WPF application and attaching a handler to the `PreviewMouseUp` event. You will see that it is only raised when you lift your finger off a pressed mouse button.

So this means that it is *your* code that is causing that behaviour and as you haven't shown us the relevant section (or indeed any code), we cannot help you with this further. I suggest searching your application for `PreviewMouseUp` to see if this event is being manually raised anywhere.